# Finding the value to prove a polynomial inequality

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

We have $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $a > b$. Let $c \in \mathbb{R}^+$. We want to find an $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $n^a > c \times n^b$.

(Really the question ask to prove for call $a, b$ if $a > b$  then for all $c$ there exists an $n$ where $n^a > cn^b$, but I really just need help seeing if the way I am finding the proper $n$ value is valid)

My method for finding the value for $n$ is:

$n^a > cn^b$

$\frac{n^a}{n^b} > c $

$n^{a-b} > c$

$(n^{a-b})^{\frac{1}{a-b}} > c^{\frac{1}{a-b}}$  (Im assuming this is possible because a > b so (a - b) > 0)

$n > c^{\frac{1}{a-b}}$

So we can choose $n = c^{\frac{1}{a-b}} + 1$

Then for the proof I just work backwards starting from $n = c^{\frac{1}{a-b}} + 1 > c^{\frac{1}{a-b}} $

Does this method for finding $n$ seem correct? There is a hint to use logarithms but I could not think of a way to do so.

More specifically the hint was $x > y \Leftrightarrow \log x > \log y$. Even if my method is correct is there a somewhat simple way to use logarithms?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct, and your approach is fine.

Using logarithms, something like this might have been thought about:
$$
n^a > cn^b \implies \ln n > \ln c + b \ln n \implies (a-b) \ln n > \ln c \\ \implies \ln n > \frac{\ln c}{a-b} \implies n > c^{\frac{1}{a-b}}
$$

The first implication follows from the natural logarithm being an increasing function, and the last from the exponential being an increasing function. All  the others are simple transpositions.

Comment: Thank you! I am still a little confused on how you get from $ln n > \frac{ln c}{a-b}$ to $n > c^{\frac{1}{a-b}}$ however.

Comment: So, if $\ln n > \frac{\ln c}{a-b}$, then first exponentiate both sides to get $e^{\ln n} > e^{\frac{\ln c}{a-b}}$. The left hand side is just $n$, the right hand side is $e^{\ln c \times \frac{1}{a-b}} = (e^{\ln c})^\frac{1}{a-b} = c^{\frac 
 1 {a-b}}$. Hence, the conclusion.